# Block Confirm not hitting Item command when click OK in chrome

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, telerik

Radconfirm when clicked 'OK' no action taken place. But works correctly on IE, Edge, Firefox but not on chrome.

The code actually is working code and was working fine couple weeks ago and no major changes have been done. But now it is firing the item command when clicked OK button on the confirm pop up in chrome.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lblUpdatePayer" Text="Update Payer" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="return blockConfirm('Make sure you have checked the next claim date to ensure that there is enough time to set up this Direct Debit', event, 330, 100,'','Update Payer');" 
    CommandName="updatepayer" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("orderid")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Is this due to the Telerik UI version? If so I am using '2018.2.516.45' The problem only persists on chrome